# Disable "root" Login

Tags: login, root

I enabled logging in as "root" on the login screen in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS by setting a password for it using the "passwd" command. How do I disable it now that I finished using the account?

Answer (score 4):

Lock it with:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options here, you can lock the root account with `sudo passwd -l root` which is the safest variant of doing this.

```
 sudo passwd -l root
```

**Beware the below method is not recommended at all!**

Or you can edit the `/etc/shadow` file and replace root's encrypted password with a `!`. The line should look then similar to this:

**(don't change the rest of the numbers if they're different on your system, only the password which is after the first double-colon)**

```
root:!:17460:0:99999:7:::
```

As I said above you should stick to the first method as long it not fails you, the second approach is having the risk that you mess it up and bork up your system.